# How to compute multiply in SUM of PigLatin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a Pig DESCRIBE like that:

```
DESCRIBE B;
B: {group: chararray, A: {name: chararray,age: int,gpa: float}}
```

I want to compute `∑B.A.gpa2` in Pig

but if i write:

```
FOREACH B {
    out = SUM(A.gpa * A.gpa);
}
```

It throw out a exeception like that:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1039: <file test.pig, line xx, column xx> (Name: Multiply Type: null Uid: null)incompatible types in Multiply Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(gpa:float)  right hand side:bag :tuple(gap:float)
```

I have ask Pig group for the solution, this is the jira [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2754)

Do some one have other suggestion with my problem ?

My temporary solution is

```
FOREACH B {
    tmp_out = FOREACH A GENERATE gpa*gap;
    out = SUM(tmp_out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your temporary solution is the correct for PIG. Remember that PIG is a simple dataflow language which can give you 95% of the solutions out of the box, the remaining 5% you can do via UDFs. To see good examples of how to write UDFs look into [DataFu by LinkedIn](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/tree/master/src/java/datafu/pig).